# Python 3.9.7 script failing to run on ubuntu crontab

Tags: python, linux, cron

I am currently attempting to setup a raspberry pi 4 as an intercom system using ubuntu 21.10. I am using functioning python scripts to play mp3s via cron jobs.

My scripts are almost exactly the same as this except for differing mp3 files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pygame import mixer
from pygame import time
mixer.init(frequency=90000, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=512)
mixer.music.load("/home/intercompi/Music/0min-closing.mp3")
mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)
mixer.music.play()

while mixer.music.get_busy():
    time.Clock().tick(10)
quit()
```

My crontab is as follows:

```
30 20 * * 1-4 /home/intercompi/30min-closing.py >> IntercomOutput.txt 2>&1
45 20 * * 1-4 /home/intercompi/15min-closing.py >> IntercomOutput.txt 2>&1
55 20 * * 1-4 /home/intercompi/5min-closing.py >> IntercomOutput.txt 2>&1
0 21 * * 1-4 /home/intercompi/0min-closing.py >> IntercomOutput.txt 2>&1
30 17 * * 0,5,6 /home/intercompi/30min-closing.py >> IntercomOutput.txt 2>&1
45 17 * * 0,5,6 /home/intercompi/15min-closing.py >> IntercomOutput.txt 2>&1
55 17 * * 0,5,6 /home/intercompi/5min-closing.py >> IntercomOutput.txt 2>&1
0 18 * * 0,5,6 /home/intercompi/0min-closing.py >> IntercomOutput.txt 2>&1
```

and my logging file outputs this:

```
/bin/sh: 1: usr/bin/python3: not found
/bin/sh: 1: usr/bin/python3: not found
/bin/sh: 1: usr/bin/python3: not found
```

I am fairly inexperienced with linux so I apologize if this is sloppy. This is partly a consolidation of my previous attempts at looking into this issue.

Comment: The error message says you left out the initial `/` in `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @Barmar, I have the `/` placed at the start of my code in the shebang line. Is there another place it needs to be?

Comment: You wouldn't be getting that error if the shebang line were being used.

Comment: `env` finds `python3` in your `$PATH`. Maybe the file that's being found is a script, and it use `usr/bin/python3` without the initial `/`. Use `type python3` to find the file that's being used, and check how it works.

Comment: An important information is missing - do your scripts work from the command line (without the cron)?

Comment: Note that `cron` doesn't run your `.bashrc`. So if you customize `PATH` there, it won't be used. So `env` will use the system-wide default `PATH`. It's probably best to use the actual path to `python3` in the shebang line, as in Hamed's answer.

Comment: @VPfB yes, they are working fine in terminal.

Comment: This is really strange. A problem with the shebang line usually results in "bad interpreter : No such file or directory"

Comment: This is only a workaround: try this crontab command: `/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/python3 /home/intercompi/30min-closing.py >> /PUT/ABSOLUTE/PATH/ALSO/HERE/IntercomOutput.txt 2>&1"` It does not rely on a shebang or PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Does "/usr/bin/env python3" on command line navigates you to python console ?

you can also use the output of the "which" command in your script.

```
which python3
```

for instance

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pygame import mixer
from pygame import time
mixer.init(frequency=90000, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=512)
mixer.music.load("/home/intercompi/Music/0min-closing.mp3")
mixer.music.set_volume(0.7)
mixer.music.play()

while mixer.music.get_busy():
    time.Clock().tick(10)
quit()
```

Comment: Use `type`, not `which`.

Comment: I just attempted this, and I am now receiving "permission denied" in regards to my python script

Comment: @CPro Make sure it has execure permission set.